# Windows7 command: set http_proxy and bypass

Tags: windows-7, command-line, proxy, http-proxy

I am sitting behind a company proxy. To start vagrant i had to use

```
set HTTP_proxy=http://http-proxy.example.org:9999
```

i tryed using `netsh winhttp` but that didn't work. So now my command line uses the proxy, but now it also uses it for `localhost` / `127.0.0.1`.

Is there a way to bypass the proxy?

I already tryed setting no_proxy like this

```
set no_proxy=localhost;127.0.0.*
```

Comment: Is your proxy properly configured in Internet Explorer?

Comment: @DanielB Yes it is and i tried `netsh winhttp import proxy source=ie` as well.

Comment: I guess that would've been too easy. Still, I believe setting the WinHTTP proxy isn't going to help either. Instead, you might want to take a look at [vagrant-proxyconf](https://github.com/tmatilai/vagrant-proxyconf).

Comment: *been there, done that*: `vagrant-proxyconf` is configured and works, otherwise i wouldn't be able to get to the point where i can not connect to the VM in the first place :(

Answer (score 15, accepted):

1. Specify multiple no_proxy hosts separated by commas, not semicolons.
2. Also, by convention Windows/DOS environment variables should be all uppercase (although I would hope most tools would ignore case).

   set NO_PROXY=localhost,127.0.0.*

From the [Python 2 docs for urllib](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#high-level-interface):

> The no_proxy environment variable can be used to specify hosts which shouldn’t be reached via proxy; if set, it should be a comma-separated list of hostname suffixes, optionally with :port appended, for example cern.ch,ncsa.uiuc.edu,some.host:8080.